# Citing foreign language sources (Swedish) in MLA7 bibliography?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, translation, mla

I'm unsure of whether or not I should cite a *foreign language source* (Swedish), with the original (Swedish) title, or use a translated English language title. The paper is for university-level coursework.

For example (using: http://debatt.svt.se/2012/08/17/svenska-journalister-ljuger-om-assange/):

> Original (Swedish) title: svenska journalister ljuger om Assange
>
> English: Swedish journalists lying about Assange

The validity of the translation is vulnerable to question, however I plan on using only *verified* English translations from both media, and governmental (Swedish judiciary) sources.

Answer (score 2):

MLA doesn't specify how to format articles with foreign titles, but for books it specifies that you should include a translation of the title after the foreign title, and it should be italicized and in brackets.

I'd say it's safe to adopt the same convention for articles.

In either case, the first title should be the foreign language title as it is specified in the source document.